# Guess at runtime fields used in equals()

Tags: java, runtime, field, equals

Is it possible to guess programmatically at runtime which fields are
used by equals() method of an object I don't own ? Especially when
getters are not used by equals() to access fields :

```
    class OverrideEquals {
        String firstField;
        Integer secondField = 0;

        @Override public boolean equals(Object other) {
           if ( other instanceof OverrideEquals ) {
               return lastField.equals(((OverrideEquals) other).lastField);
           }
           return false;
        }
    }
```

In this example, is there a way to know equals() uses firstField and not lastField (byte-code analysis, proxy,...) at the moment it is invoked ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decompiling the bytecode would give you that answer, but an easier and more logical way to do it would be to ask the code owner to annotate their `equals` method in some way, e.g. `@ChecksForEqualityOn(...)`.

Is there a particular reason you need to do this at runtime?